# how to decode this string TT_x0040__x0040__x0024__x0025_ in c#

Tags: c#

I receive the following string through a REST API. But it consists of special characters. The actual string is TT@@$% which is received as TT_x0040__x0040__x0024__x0025_
Please help me in getting back to the original string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encoded with (or some equivalent):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Decode:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.decodename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx